# Is a Site Column related to a web or site collection

Tags: 2010, site-collection, site-column, web

just going through some slides for SharePoint 2010 Developer Certification slides and it says Site Columns are related to web, but I thought they are created on site collection level, can someone explain the concept of it for me please.

Comment: Site Columns are created at the Site Collection level but they can be localized at the Site Level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look @ [Introduction to Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms450825.aspx)

Specially look at the Column Scope section, which says Site Columns scope is same as Content Types...!

> Also like content types, site columns are available to all the child
>   sites of the site on which they are defined.
>
> At the site level, the site column collection contains definitions for
>   each site column defined on the site, whether or not it has been added
>   to a content type or list on that site.

I hope this explains...

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint also offers you the possibility to create Site Columns. What are these? They are columns that we create in a SharePoint site to be available to its’ sub sites.

[image]
SharePoint Columns, Site Columns and Content Types explained
As you can see when you create a SharePoint Site Column it is available to the site and its’ sub-sites. This makes it very interesting for us to reuse a configuration.

For more info [see](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-columns-site-columns-or-content-types)